# What does the underscore mean in the typedef structure?

Tags: c++, c, structure, typedef

I was reading the source code of zmq, and came across the following `typedef`

```
typedef struct {unsigned char _ [32];} zmq_msg_t;
```

I don't understand what the underscore means in this definition. Could someone please help shed some light?

Comment: It is just a variable name.

Comment: Note: C11 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers: "... All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."  Here `_` is a field name so appears to not violate this.

Comment: @chux Namespaces are defined in 6.2.3

Comment: @OrangeDog: The question is unfortunately tagged as both C and C++.

Comment: In the particular case of zmq, this is likely a means of not publicly declaring a usable message format while guaranteeing that the message itself is exactly 32 bytes long.

Comment: I had a similar confusion when learning Javascript. What the hell is `$` and how does it do all the magic ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An underscore (`_`) is a valid identifier, in this case, a name of the member of the structure. It does not have any *special* meaning, as such.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.2.1, *Identifiers*

> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore `_`, the
>   lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates
>   one or more entities [....]

AFAIR, this is true in case of C++, also, refer chapter 2.11, C++14.

Answer (score 19):

It doesn't mean anything, it's simply the name of the structure member.

It's not the most communicative name, but it's probably chosen to be a bit "secret".

An identifier basically has to match `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*`, and this one does.

Answer (score 12):

In several languages there is a convention to use the identifier `_` for "don't care" variables that are not supposed to ever be referenced.  For example, you could write in Scheme/Lisp

```
(let* ((x ...)
       (_ ...<some side effect depending on x>)
       (y ...<something making use of the side effect's result>))
  ...)
```

In this case there is no problem with scoping since you can reassign `_` as often as you want.  In C/C++ this convention is not all that workable since more often than not several uses of `_` would conflict.  It is not necessary for ignored parameters since you can just omit them altogether:

```
int fun(int a, int, int b) { return a + b; }
```

However, as sole size substitute in a structure (for which it is used here), you cannot omit the identifier, and you'll only ever need one identifier per namespace.  So in this case, this convention works out.  But as an idiomatic pattern, it is used in other languages a whole lot more.

Answer (score 3):

From cppreference, for not having a copy of Standard by me:

> An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of digits, underscores,
>   lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and most Unicode characters

Thus, `_` is a variable name. See also

[What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

for reference on using underscores in identifiers

Comment: `_` is a field name.  This is no variable in OP's code.

Comment: @chux: If you must go to that level of pedantry, you'll have to pick some other term than "field", since neither C++ nor C defines that term. It's made up. Personally, I think "variable" is just fine; "member variable" is acceptable colloquially. The real term you're looking for is "data member".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agree about weakness of "field".  _data member_ is better.  BTW _filed_ is not made up by me, just an term for a sub-portion of a data record in [another language](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-13.html)

Comment: @chux: In the context of C++, it's made up ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit May we compromise and say _field_ was used in the general sense of computer science as detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(computer_science)) and not a a C/C++ defined term?

Comment: @chux: Yes. :-) But note that the same text promotes variants on "variable" too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you are taking orders, I prefer my [Humble pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humble_pie) [à la mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_expressions_in_English#A_la_mode), maybe with a side dish of [crow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_crow)?

Comment: @chux: It'll be with you in just a few minutes sir :)

Answer (score 1):

In one word? Nothing. _ is a character as any other and can be used to name a variable... 
Most programmers, however, use _ to replace spaces in variable names... so, you can do something like this:
 `int my_darling_little_beloved_variable;`